# Can I hide my link flags from users of my conan package?

Tags: c++, linker-flags, conan

Let's say I have a library uploaded as a package in [conan](https://conan.io/), which uses OpenGL, and as such links with `GL` in the `CMakeLists.txt`. Do the users of the library need to explicitly link against GL again? Does conan provide a method to track it and include it in `${CONAN_LIBS}`?

The nearest thing I found in the [docs](http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile.html#c-build-information) is the method `package_info`, where it seems that you can specify linker extra options, but I don't seem to be using it properly in my library's `conanfile.py`. I tried all of:

```
    self.cpp_info.sharedlinkflags = ["-lGL", "GL", "libGL", "libGL.so", "-llibGL.so"]
```

But if in the user code I don't put the link flag, it raises "undefined reference" to GL's methods.

EDIT: I'm working in linux mint 17.

Comment: It might be helpful if you stated which operating system you are on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to declare it in the `conanfile.py` `package_info()` method, as conan decouples build (as defined in your cmake files) from package management. There is a specific attribute for libraries in the `cpp_info` attribute, which you could use:

```
def package_info(self):
    self.cpp_info.libs = ["GL"]
```

This `libs` field is transitive between dependencies, and the GL lib will be contained in the `${CONAN_LIBS}` variable

The `sharedlinkflags` is transitive too, and it ends with its values accumulated in the cmake variable `${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}`. But as its name states, it is only for shared linking, so it is likely that you are not building such a shared library, so your lib flags as `GL` are not being applied to your target.